# Linux word in column ends with 'a'

Tags: awk

I have text file. I need to print people whose names ends with 'a' and have more than 30 years.

I did this:

```
awk '{if($4>30)print $1,$2}' New.txt
```

I don't know how to finish.

New.txt:

```
Name     Lastname   City      Age
John     Smith      Verona    12
Barney   Stinson    York      55
Jessica  Alba       London    33
```

Comment: What do you mean "finish"?  What does your code not do that you want it to do?

Comment: @JaredPL please post the input file as text.  Posting an image to a text is not appropriate here.

Comment: I need to print names that ends with 'a'.

Comment: First name or last name or either name? Do you want the header? What is the field separator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written as per shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '$1~/[aA]$/ && $NF>30{print $1,$2}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply checking condition if 1st field ends with `a` OR `A` AND last field is greater than 30 then print that line's first and second fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
awk '{if($4>30 && $1 ~ /a$/) print$1, $2}' New.txt
```